# Omines Datatables with Turbo and Stimulus

Tags: symfony, datatables, turbolinks, stimulusjs

I am trying to use Turbo in a new Symfony development. I'm following [Turbo: Drive, Frames & Streams as a reference!](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/turbo/intro) and previously [Symfony UX: Stimulus](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/stimulus). Both topics are new to me and as if that weren't enough, I don't have much experience with Javascript.

All good except that I have not been able to get Omines Datatables to work under this scheme. I understand that I must create a Stimulus component but I have not achieved even the most basic thing, which is to load the Datatable.

I wonder if someone can guide me or if they have gone through the same thing, maybe they can provide a practical example of how to do it. Is it too much to ask?

In general, I usually load the Datatables in the following way:

```
{% block body %}
...
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <div id="app_provinciaList">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
                    <div class="spinner-border m-5" role="status">
                        <span class="sr-only">Cargando...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
...
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script>
        $(function () {
            
            var grillaApp_provincias = $('#app_provinciaList').initDataTables( {{ datatable_settings(datatable) }}, {               
                searching: true,
            }).then(function (dt) {
                dt.on('init', function(settings, json) {
                    $('#dt_filter input').attr("placeholder", "Provincia...");
                    $('#dt_filter input').width(300);                 
                });
            });                 
        });
    </script>

{% endblock %}
```